# I want to put textview on navigation bar for setting title at runtime through the simulator in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to put the textview on navigation bar  to set the title by user through the simulator at the run time.

Comment: You really should accept answers to your questions (all 16 of them) so that people will feel encouraged to answer them..

Answer (score 2):

Take a look `UINavigationItem`'s `titleView` property - you can place any view/control there, e.g. a `UITextField`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that there exists a title property you can set already, and you don't need a textview. If you post some code showing the problem, someone might be able to give a more specific answer.

Comment: He wants to change the title according to user input, so the `title` property of the `UINavigationItem` will not be enough.